# Add text to an input element within a canvas

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to add text to an input element which is located within a canvas. Then I would manually press the button to confirm and send the message.

```html
<div class="center">
    <div id="flash-wrapper">
        <div id="flash-content" style="visibility: visible; cursor: default;">
            <canvas width="1000" height="640" style="transform: translateZ(0px); width: 1000px; height: 640px; margin-left: 0px; margin-top: 0px; text-align: center;"></canvas>
            <form autocomplete="off">
                <button type="submit" disabled="" aria-hidden="true" style="display: none;"></button>
                <input type="text" autocapitalize="off" autocomplete="off" style="position: absolute; opacity: 0; color: transparent; box-sizing: content-box; left: 0px; top: 50%; width: 1px; height: 1px; pointer-events: none; z-index: -10000000;" />
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

What I have tried to so far is:

- change the value of input box

  - `document.querySelector("#flash-content > form > input[type=text]").value = "someText";`
- use setAttribute

  - `document.querySelector("#flash-content > form > input[type=text]").setAttribute("value", "someText");`
- use Keyboard event (also tried keyup and keypress)

  - `document.querySelector("#flash-content > form > input[type=text]").dispatchEvent(new KeyboardEvent("keydown",{key:"j", bubbles:true}))`
- use Input event

  - `document.querySelector("#flash-content > form > input[type=text]").dispatchEvent(new InputEvent("input", {isTrusted: true, data: "someText", isComposing: false, inputType: "insertText",dataTransfer: null, bubbles:true}))`

Edit: It seems that one issue might be that I can't get the wrapped input element to become the focus.

I have added an event onfocus listener

```
document.querySelector("#flash-content > form > input[type=text]").addEventListener("focus", function() {
   alert("input has focus");
}
```

and the alert pops out when I click with my mouse on the input field, but won't do so if I set

```
document.querySelector("#flash-content > form > input[type=text]").focus()
```

Comment: What exactly is your problem?